# full calendar with dropdown navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

Hi I'm a novice at HTML5.

Created a website using Bootstrap v3. Working on a webpage to utilize FullCalendar. I have one of two problems. Either the calendar works and my dropdown NavBar menus do not work. Or Vice Versa.

I've narrowed down the problem to the jquery.min.js script link.

If I comment out the script "...src='assets/js/calendar/jquery.min.js'>", then my dropdown menus, work perfectly.

If I comment out the script 
"...src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"

window.jQuery || document.write('...src="js/vendor/jquery.js">')", then my calendar works but my dropdown NavBar menus do not work.

I figured out the Bootstrap jquery script is using version 1.11.2 and FullCalendar is using version 3.1.1.

Then I downloaded Bootstrap v4 Alpha. The link there is to jquery-slim.min.js is version 3.1.1 so I thought this might solve my problem. I put together a test webpage and still experiencing the same issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: you only need one version of jquery in your page. avoid jquery slim - it's missing a lot of functions, and you don't know if the other plugins rely on them or not.

Comment: @vanburen This is what is being used in the <head> tag. <script src='assets/js/calendar/jquery.min.js'></script>

Comment: @vanburen This is what is being used in the <body> tag.  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: @ADyson Don't understand. Can I eliminate the all of the jquery.min.js files? Except for one of them. I did try to comment out the jquery scripts but as I stated, if I comment out the scripts in the header tag then my FullCalendar doesn't work. If I comment out the scripts in the body tag then my drop down menus cease to work. .

Comment: @ADyson It was the "jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" that was giving me a hard time. When I comment out that script, both my calendar and drop down menus both work. Thank you.

Comment: yep that's because jQuery slim is a cut-down version of jquery. Not all the functions that are needed by the calendar and dropdowns are present. And your next bit of code only loads the full jQuery if no previous jQuery has been loaded. Since you'd already loaded jQuery slim, it didn't run.